# Ugrading to a new iMac?

Tags: macos, time-machine

I have a 2017 21" iMac, I'm thinking of getting a new 2019 27" model in a few weeks, are all the programs that I have bought on the app store saved to my Apple ID? so if I go to the app store on the new machine, I just need to re-download them again (for free), or would the best way to do it, by making a backup using time machine and installing that from the ext HDD to the new Mac? doing it that way, would it fully install all the programs I already have (inc ones not from the app store)....and would it install all my saved passwords etc? I'm fairy new to Macs, so what would be the best/easiest way to do this? The instructions for time machine seem quite straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

All the apps which you have previously purchased, and which are running on your present iMac, are available in the App Store for re-download. However, the best method for transferring your present user account(s) and apps to your new iMac is through [Time Machine Migration Assistant](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204350), which will be one of the first options when you set up the new iMac out of the box. Make sure you have a current backup of your present machine *and* that the Time Machine device itself (External USB drive, etc) can be physically connected to the new iMac.

Just recently I upgraded to a 2019 iMac myself, and because I have loads of Thunderbolt drives, including my main Time Machine drive, I had to purchase Apple Thunderbolt > USBC adapters to do the migration and continue to use the drive as the Time Machine backup disk.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds straight forward enough

Comment: I've done it many times for myself, family members, and clients.